# I cant extract name using duckling in rasa 2.0

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, duckling

I want to extract name using duckling but keep failing saing that "faild to extract requested slot 'name's "..can anyone explain me

Answer (score 0):

Duckling does not extract names. It specializes in regularly patterned entities like numbers and dates. See their [list of supported dimensions](https://github.com/facebook/duckling#supported-dimensions). SpaCy offers pretrained models that usually have a `PERSON` dimension which might be what you want. See e.g. [the label scheme for the English models](https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_sm-labels)

Comment: Thank you....here duckling also extracts duration right...and j see it has two value the first one and the normalized and..and I I want rasa to catch that ..is that possible in custom action??

Comment: That sounds like a very different question  to the one posted - in short yes, it extracts duration, and yes, you can parse this out in a custom action. If you have a different question though, it's better to post it as a new question to make it easier for others with the same question to find.